# Background color in List element

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a list, every element has some strings and image, how can i change background color (LinearLayot) of every element?

My code:

1)Arrays in Activity.java

```
 ListView listview;
    int[] list_photo = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e};
    String[] list_name = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    String[] list_email = {"a@", "b@", "c@", "d@", "e@"};
    String[] list_phone = {"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12"};
    TrainersAdapter adapter;
```

and in OnCreate in Actvity.java

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.trainerslist);
        adapter = new TrainersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_trainers);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TrainersDataProvider dataProvider = new TrainersDataProvider(list_photo[i], list_name[i], list_email[i], list_phone[i]);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
        }
```

2)Then i have adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by dd on 2016-03-06.
 */
public class TrainersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public TrainersAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class Datahandler{
        ImageView photo;
        TextView name;
        TextView email;
        TextView phone;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        Datahandler handler;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_trainers,parent,false);
            handler = new Datahandler();
            handler.photo=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainerslist_photo);
            handler.name=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainerslist_name);
            handler.email=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainerslist_email);
            handler.phone=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.trainerslist_phone);
            row.setTag(handler);
        }
        else{
            handler = (Datahandler) row.getTag();
        }
        TrainersDataProvider dataProvider;
        dataProvider = (TrainersDataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        handler.photo.setImageResource(dataProvider.getTrainer_photo());
        handler.name.setText(dataProvider.getTrainer_name());
        handler.email.setText(dataProvider.getTrainer_email());
        handler.phone.setText(dataProvider.getTrainer_phone());

        return row;
    }
}
```

3) and Dataprovider

```
public class TrainersDataProvider {

    private int trainer_photo;
    private String trainer_name;
    private String trainer_email;
    private String trainer_phone;

    public TrainersDataProvider(int trainer_photo,String trainer_name, String trainer_email, String trainer_phone){
        this.setTrainer_photo(trainer_photo);
        this.setTrainer_email(trainer_email);
        this.setTrainer_name(trainer_name);
        this.setTrainer_phone(trainer_phone);
    }

    public String getTrainer_email() {
        return trainer_email;
    }

    public void setTrainer_email(String trainer_email) {
        this.trainer_email = trainer_email;
    }

    public String getTrainer_name() {
        return trainer_name;
    }

    public void setTrainer_name(String trainer_name) {
        this.trainer_name = trainer_name;
    }

    public String getTrainer_phone() {
        return trainer_phone;
    }

    public void setTrainer_phone(String trainer_phone) {
        this.trainer_phone = trainer_phone;
    }

    public int getTrainer_photo() {
        return trainer_photo;
    }

    public void setTrainer_photo(int trainer_photo) {
        this.trainer_photo = trainer_photo;
    }
}
```

I want to have array of colors in Activity.java (like photo,name,email and phone) and put it to Dataprovider constructor, this color should be background in linearlayout in list element.

Comment: could you post xml code for R.layout.list_trainers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the linearlayout an id like android:id="@+id/background_layout". Then define it in Datahandler as LinearLayout background, initialize it handler.background=(LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.background_layout); and do handler.backgorund.setBackgroundColor(color from your arrayList);

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the background color programatically?  In the `#onCreate` method you have access to the `ListView` which extends from `View` which has `View#setBackgroundColor` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)).